# Como gravar dados em uma tabela um para muitos?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

estou com uma duvida que ainda persiste após fazer algumas buscas.

É o seguinte, supondo que eu tenho um formulario, onde cadastro varios emails  para um unico usuário, como eu gravo esses vários emails na tabela deles? Segue os exemplos: *(se tiver algum erro fiquem a vontade para corrigir)*

**Models e ViewModel:**

```
 public class Email
{
    public int EmailID { get; set; }
    public int UsuarioID { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UsuarioID")]
    public virtual Usuario Usuarios { get; set; }
}

public class Usuario
{
    public int UsuarioID { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Email> Emails { get; set; }
}

public class UsuarioNovo
{
    [Required]
    public int Nome { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "E-mail")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

No html, criei uma div com a classe `.dc-box-clonar` com os inputs e um script no js para clonar a div ao clicar em um determinado link, segue o script:

```
$('.dc-box-clonar').hide();
$('.control-add-box').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var newElem = $(this).parent().find('.dc-box-clonar:first').clone();
    newElem.find('input').val('');
    newElem.prependTo($(this).parent()).show();
    var height = $(this).prev('.dc-box-clonar').outerHeight(true);

    $("html, body").stop().animate({ scrollTop: $(this).offset().top - 520 }, 600);
});
```

Como ficaria o Controller com instruções EF? E esse modo de clonar no js da certo nessa ocasião?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sua pergunta é mais uma das clássicas perguntas que pedem o uso do [BeginCollectionItem](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A2999+begincollectionitem), mas há alguns adendos a se fazer.

A convenção de nomes de *Models* normalmente é no singular, porque cada *Model* identifica uma entidade **no singular**:

```
public class Email
{
    public int EmailID { get; set; }
    public int UsuarioID { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UsuarioID")]
    public virtual Usuario Usuario { get; set; }
}
```

Outra coisa é que este é o mapeamento de cardinalidade 1 para N. Ou seja, em `Usuario` você pode declarar que a entidade possui vários `Email`:

```
public class Usuario
{
    public int UsuarioID { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }

    // Essa declaração agora sim é no plural.
    public virtual ICollection<Email> Emails { get; set; }
}
```

O script de clonar a div aparentemente está ok, mas há alguns detalhes que você precisa atentar:

- Se você vai usar o [BeginCollectionItem](https://www.nuget.org/packages/BeginCollectionItem/), a clonagem precisa passar pelo *Controller* para definir a chave temporária (o que é o recomendado);
- Se você não usar, vai precisar definir seu `<form>` de modo que o atributo `name` de cada `<input>` seja identificado por um índice (de preferência numérico). Além disso, esse índice precisa estar contido em um campo adicional no `<form>` chamado `index`. Por exemplo:

O que o [BeginCollectionItem](https://www.nuget.org/packages/BeginCollectionItem/) faz é isto: criar este esquema de `<form>` automaticamente pra você.

Com isso, você pode usar no *Controller* apenas isto:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Salvar(Usuario usuario) 
{
    /* Usuario.Emails estará preenchido com os e-mails da tela. */
}
```

Comment: Valeu Mestre Cigano! haha Mas o que você quer dizer com : a clonagem precisa passar pelo Controller?

Comment: O JavaScript chama uma *Partial* que monta a linha certinho pra você. Se precisar de exemplos nisso, abra outra pergunta.

Comment: Ok, vou dar uma pesquisada aqui e caso não consiga achar algo ou não esteja entendendo, dou um pulo aqui

Comment: No Controller eu preciso declarar o que vai no ICollection e iniciar ele junto com a view? Pois aqui quando vou dar mostrar a PartialView na View principal é retornado uma NullReferenceException:  "Referência de objeto não definida para uma instância de um objeto."

Comment: Sim, pode iniciar a `ICollection` com um objeto vazio.

Comment: Mas quando tento iniciar com ICollection, o VS aponta que não pode instanciar uma classe abstrata. Com List ele não aponta essa exceção.

Comment: Agora eu acho que é uma excelente hora de abrir outra pergunta.

Comment: Então não teria como vc complementar essa resposta mesmo? Porque basicamente a pergunta permaneceria a mesma...

Comment: Não porque você já começou a ter erros, e bem que eu gostaria de conseguir ler sua tela agora, mas não consigo. Então por favor abra outra pergunta contendo exatamente o problema que você está tendo.